# Prevent AJAX requests in Chrome/Firefox after initial load

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a page in Chrome. Every few seconds the page issues AJAX requests that update elements on the page. Is there a DevTools option to stop these page requests? It makes debugging HTML/CSS difficult since the DOM is reset.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a little harsh, but you could override the XMLHttpRequest's call method, then it won't do anything

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.call = function () {};
```

Type that statement into the console panel of the page your debugging. A page refresh will reset the native functionality.

Comment: You mean `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open`?  Nowadays also do `fetch = () => {};` and `navigator.sendBeacon = () => {};`.

Answer (score 5):

Open Chrome DevTools. 
Make a breakpoint in the line that you think it will be run before AJAX requests. Javascript will stop running until you press 'resume' button.
Ps: you will see the page's original style. But it's still hard to change html or css in console. So this may not be the best answer!

Comment: I put a break on <html> and it is solved! Hit F12 to open chrome console, go to elements tab, right-click on <html>, Break ON -> Subtree modifications.

Comment: On a page which performs an ajax call right after its first load, I could only use breakpoints

Answer (score 5):

On dev tools:

Three vertical dots icon >> Network conditions >> Offline present

[image]

[image]

Comment: On certain versions of Chrome (on mine at least) Network conditions was hidden under "More Tools" after clicking on the three dots.

Comment: F12 - in the console click "Network" - Put checkmark on "Offline" checkbox.